# jQuery else statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm having a problem with my else statement.. It doesn't seem to be executed.. What I want is if I click on the button "dissapear" all Paragraphs with "Boe" dissapears, but if i click on it again, it appears back. But my else statement doesnt seem to work, the same with the "change" button, if i click on "change", my text formats itself, but if i click on it once more, it goes back to normal. Any help? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table").css("border","solid black 4px");
        $("#dissapear").click(function(){
            if ($(".boe:visible")) {
                $(".boe").hide(1000);
            } else {
                ($(".boe:visible"))
            }
        });

        $("#change").click(function(){
            if ($(".hoera").css("color","black")) {
                $(".hoera").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});
                $(".boe").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});
            } else {
                $(".hoera").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});
                $(".boe").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});
            }
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<div id="tabel">
    <table>
        <td> <button id="dissapear">Dissapear!</button> </td>
        <td> <button id="change">Change!</button> </td>
        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p>  </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td></tr> 
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>  </td></tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p></td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery does not have statements. `($(".boe:visible"))` does not do anything useful.

Comment: I think you should read up more on what the functions you're calling actually do. Another suspect line: `if ($(".hoera").css("color","black"))`, which changes the color to black and returns a jQuery object, and will always be true. http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `toggle()` to hide/show. And `$(".hoera:first-child").css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"` to compare the current color.

Here's the answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table").css("border","solid black 4px");
        $("#dissapear").click(function(){
            $(".boe").toggle(1000);
        });

        $("#change").click(function(){
            if ($(".hoera:first-child").css("color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
                $(".hoera").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});
                $(".boe").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});
            } else {
                $(".hoera").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});
                $(".boe").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<div id="tabel">
    <table>
        <td> <button id="dissapear">Dissapear!</button> </td>
        <td> <button id="change">Change!</button> </td>
        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p>  </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td></tr> 
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>  </td></tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        <tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p></td> </tr>

        <tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, why is the "first-child" needed? I tried removing it and it works just fine without it, what does it do? What does it mean? Thank you!

Comment: It is not necessarily. I just placed it to get the specific first child of class `hoera` because as we know it using `class` will select a multiple elements. For your reference, [CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table").css("border","solid black 4px");

$("#dissapear").click(function(){

if ($(".boe").is(":visible")) 
    {

            $(".boe").hide(1000);

    }   
    else 
    {
    $(".boe").show();
    }

});



$("#change").click(function() 
{
    if ($(".hoera").css("color","black"))
    {

         $(".hoera").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});
            $(".boe").css({"color":"green","font-size":"40px","text-decoration":"underline"});

    }


        else 
        {
        $(".hoera").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});
        $(".boe").css({"color":"black","text-decoration":"none","font-size":"19px"});

        }

});  





});
</script>
</head>
<div id="tabel">
<table>
<td> <button id="dissapear">Dissapear!</button> </td>
<td> <button id="change">Change!</button> </td>
<tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
<tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

<tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p>  </td> </tr>
<tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p> </td> </tr>

<tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td></tr> 
<tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>  </td></tr>

<tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>
<tr><td> <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p></td> </tr>

<tr><td> <p class="boe">BOE!</p> </td> </tr>

</tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your if statement will always be true because it is aiming the wrong attribute instead the one from CSS. The following code works just fine for me:

```
if ($(".boe").css("display") != "none"){

    $(".boe").hide(1000);
    $("#dissapear").text("Appear!");

}else{

    $(".boe").show(1000);
    $("#disapear").text("Disapear!");

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table").css("border", "solid black 4px");

  $("#dissapear").click(function() {

    var boes = $('.boe').filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
    })

    if (boes.length == 0) {
      $(".boe").hide(1000);
    } else {
      $(".boe").show(1000)
    }
  });

  $("#change").click(function() {
    var hoeras = $('.hoera').filter(function() {
      return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    })

    if (hoeras.length > 0) {
      $(".hoera").css({
        "color": "green",
        "font-size": "40px",
        "text-decoration": "underline"
      });
      $(".boe").css({
        "color": "green",
        "font-size": "40px",
        "text-decoration": "underline"
      });

    } else {
      $(".hoera").css({
        "color": "black",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "font-size": "19px"
      });
      $(".boe").css({
        "color": "black",
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "font-size": "19px"
      });

    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabel">
  <table>
    <td> <button id="dissapear">Dissapear!</button> </td>
    <td> <button id="change">Change!</button> </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="boe">BOE!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="boe">BOE!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="boe">BOE!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="boe">BOE!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="hoera">Hoera!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="boe">BOE!</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```